# Customize primary key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

How to create customize primary key in MySQL?, example i have table and the table name is `X`, I have a table field as `ID`,`Code`,`Name`.

> I am afraid **if I have 1000 users** and when they input together will
>   **result in destruction**

and i want to :

```
INSERT INTO `X` (`ID`,`Code`,`Name`) VALUES 
('P3K','Alex'), // this primary key is "P3K-1"
('SOS','Force'), // this primary key is "SOS-1"
('P3K','Bash'), // this primary key is "P3K-2"
```

Right now, i using TRIGGER (*BEFORE INSERT*) for this, like this one:

```
SET NEW.`ID` = CONCAT(NEW.`Code`,'-',IFNULL(SUBSTRING_INDEX((
  SELECT `x`.`Code` FROM `X` WHERE 
    X.`Code` = NEW.`Code` and 
ORDER BY X.`Code` DESC
LIMIT 1 ),'-',-1),0) + 1))
```

I did not try this code, but my point is:

1. User insert
2. Before insert I checking LAST Primary
3. IF Null then i set 0, else i cut the symbol (-) and take the last part
4. I increments (using [+ 1])
5. Final, i concat `CODE` and New Number.

am i misguided? LOL, and if true, how to create like this one?
**(I THINK)** We can do it and **maybe** no one knows about this, how does AI in MySQL work so perfectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from him (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1133682/mjh)

InnoDB is very dependent on PRIMARY KEY using Auto Incremment, if you do not use Auto Incremment then you will spend space. each line by adding at least 6-8 bytes just to make the "HIDDEN PRIMARY KEY", and the best use of innoDB is USE Auto Incremment and do not disturb that key, if you want to add UNIQUE KEY then you just have to CONCAT

Answer (score -1):

Instead of having the hyphenated string as the primary key, you can store the code and number as separate fields, use them together as the primary key, and optionally have the hyphenated string as a generated column. This is how `CREATE TABLE` would look for such a table

```
CREATE TABLE X (
    Code       CHAR(3),
    Number     INT,
    Name       VARCHAR(20),
    CodeNumber VARCHAR(8) AS (CONCAT(Code, '-', Number)),

    PRIMARY KEY (Code, Number)
);
```

Then you `BEFORE INSERT` trigger becomes

```
SET NEW.Number = (1 + IFNULL((SELECT Number FROM X WHERE Code = NEW.Code 
                                     ORDER BY Number DESC LIMIT 1), 0))
```

Comment: is this safe?, how to know this safe way?

Comment: @AbdulAzizAlBasyir I tested it before posting the answer and it works fine. In fact, I'd say its safer than the method you used in your question.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for your answer, and where do you try it? I want to try it too as a lesson for me

Comment: @AbdulAzizAlBasyir I have XAMPP's PHPmyAdmin constantly running on my system. I can open my browser at any time, navigate to `localhost/phpmyadmin`, create a database, and run any SQL query I want.

Comment: I think you use "benchmark", do you use it?, if i have 1000 connection and they are together inputs,is there a problem with your query?

Comment: Nope. I don't use it. But if concurrency is an issue, MySQL has lots of ways to ensure that.

Comment: (if you know) how to do the test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155252/discussion-between-leo-aso-and-abdul-aziz-al-basyir).